# Mind teaser SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been trying to answer the questions found on http://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php#answer_ref recently since I am a newbie in sql, as you can see from my previous posts regarding sql.  I across this question:

> Exercise: 23 Find the makers producing at least both a pc having speed not less than 750 MHz and a laptop having speed not less than 750 MHz. Result set: Maker

The following is my answer which is incorrect since it uses or.  can anyone guide me to a good direction by either giving me a link where to search or what join should I use.

```
  SELECT pt.maker    
    FROM product pt, 
         laptop l, 
         pc    
   WHERE (pt.model = pc.model 
     AND pc.speed >=750) 
      OR (pt.model = l.model 
     AND l.speed >=750)
GROUP BY pt.maker
```

Comment: Please Note this is not a school exercise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close, if the tables and column definitions are right (I don't have a login for that site), it should be something like:

```
SELECT distinct pt_pc.maker
FROM  
  laptop l 
    inner join product pt_l on pt_l.model=l.model, 
  pc
    inner join product pt_pc on pt_pc.model=pc.model
WHERE pc.speed >=750 and l.speed >=750 and pt_l.maker=pt_pc.maker
```

so basically you want one pc with speed >=750 and one laptop with speed >=750 made by the same guy.

Comment: I would be consistent with the use of inner join though. mixed join styles are confusing

Comment: 10x for your anser :)  since you know it, can you please explain to me the difference between your answer and the following SELECT p.maker
FROM product p inner join laptop l on p.model = l.model
inner join pc on p.model = pc.model

Comment: @Ian, one `product` table row can't match both a `pc` and a `laptop` model at the same time. You need two, one for each model.

Comment: @Filip, While I can do it all with joins, this query doesn't exactly make sense like that. It's really two different joins matched by the `where` clause.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `INTERSECT` is supported:

```
SELECT  maker
FROM    product p
JOIN    laptop l
ON      l.model = p.model
WHERE   speed >= 750
INTERSECT
SELECT  maker
FROM    product p
JOIN    pc
ON      pc.model = p.model
WHERE   speed >= 750
```

Cross-platform:

```
SELECT  maker
FROM    (
        SELECT  maker, 1 AS source
        FROM    product p
        JOIN    laptop l
        ON      l.model = p.model
        WHERE   speed >= 750
        UNION
        SELECT  maker, 2 AS source
        FROM    product p
        JOIN    pc
        ON      pc.model = p.model
        WHERE   speed >= 750
        ) q
GROUP BY
        maker
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: I wonder if this gets turned into a join or if it scans the table twice.

Comment: i think that your second solution (Cross-platform is not correct) assuming that a maker has 2 laptops and no pcs or on the other hand 5 laptops and 2 pcs. the count would not match. please correct me if i am mistaken

Comment: @IanCian: you would be correct if I used `UNION ALL` but `UNION` eliminates the duplicates. And why is cross-platform not correct? Which major platform does not support it?

Comment: 10x for helping me understand better :)

Comment: +1 for `INTERSECT` which really should be cross-platform because after all it is one of Codd's five [primitive relational operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker 
FROM product 
WHERE   maker IN (SELECT DISTINCT maker 
                  FROM product AS a 
                  INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT model 
                              FROM pc 
                              WHERE speed>=750) AS b  ON a.model=b.model)
        AND maker IN (SELECT DISTINCT maker 
                      FROM product AS a 
                      INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT model 
                                  FROM laptop 
                                  WHERE speed>=750) AS b ON a.model=b.model)
```